# how to know the users that visited my profile in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a simple user model that was generated through devise,  is there a way or any way a user knows another user visited their profile using a gem or any other resource... or is there any other way i can use the public activity gem to track users visits on another users page

my users controller show action is thus

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :show]
 def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Mhhh...You could create a table where you have 2 columns: visitor and user_visited. Everytime a user visits another user profile you could save it in the table

Comment: nice insight... could you help me with the whole mark up here ... plssssssssssssss. and i appreciate the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem will do what you want and more.

Comment: the gem is awesome .. but how do i know that a particular user viewed the show action e.g user.username viewed @user's profile thanks

Comment: The docs are pretty clear. If you follow the installation and usage instructions then the details will be written to the impressions table.

Comment: Have a go at following the instructions. If you get stuck then ask a specific question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: i need to write this to a user e.g user1 visited your prfile... the gem only counts profile views so how do i go about this?